# How do I make a script that properly introduces hstore in both 9.0 and 9.1?

Tags: postgresql-9.1, ddl, postgresql-9.0, hstore

I am trying to introduce the `hstore` type into the database of a project I'm developing. But the problem is that I have a slightly newer version of the Postgres server installed on my development machine than there is on the production machine. While I can simply execute the `CREATE EXTENSION` command locally, this command is unavailable on the production machine.

Is there a way to create a script that will install `hstore` both on 9.1 and 9.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 9.0, you could use a script like this (ex: create_hstore.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash

DB=$1
ARGS="-U postgres -h localhost"
CONTRIB=/usr/pgsql-9.0/share/contrib

[ $# -lt 1 ] && exit 1

# Uncomment following lines if necessary
#createdb $ARGS $DB
#createlang $ARGS plpgsql $DB
psql $ARGS -f $CONTRIB/hstore.sql $DB
```

and then to invoke it:

```
./create_hstore.sh <db_name>
```

Comment: This could be it, only if there was a way to determine which PG version is currently installed in the system.

Answer (score 1):

> ... if there was a way to determine which PG version is currently installed in the system.

Ask Postgres:

```
psql -c 'select version()' postgres
```

Or, if you are confident that the version of psql is in sync:

```
psql --version
```